# Android mapview : how to zoom and center at the same time smoothly

Tags: android, android-mapview, zooming, center

It does not seem to be possible to zoom and center smoothly with the google map sdk for android...
I have been trying for hours with a timer and a combination of zoomInFixing/zoomToSpan and setCenter/animateTo but nothing works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an approach like this?

```
private void goToPoint(Double longitude, Double latitude) {

        Double latAux = latitude * 1E6;
        Double lngAux = longitude * 1E6;

        MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

        mapController.animateTo(point);
        mapController.setZoom(16);
}
```

If you pretend something more smooth you have to implement it yourself. Zoom in a delta value of the total zoom multiple times.

```
zoom = 0; 
totalZoom = 16; 
deltaZoom = 0.5;
while(zoom < totalZoom){ 
  sleep(100); 
  mapController.setZoom(zoom); 
  zoom += deltaZoom; 
}
```

Comment: unfortunately setZoom does not do a smooth zoom, it simply  show a "flash" and the new zoomed position.

Answer (score 0):

```
//setZoom is not smooth, but you can emulate that effect using an approach like this:


zoom = 0;
totalZoom = 16;
deltaZoom = 0.5;

while(zoom < totalZoom){
sleep(100);
mapController.setZoom(zoom);
zoom += deltaZoom;
}
```